# Auto layout With activity indicator puts it in the wrong place

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, uiactivityindicatorview

I have an uiactivity monitor that is experiencing and "out of body experience"

In the interface builder I put it into a xib.(colored red below) and add constraints to keep it centered horizontally and above the label below it.

I load the xib and present it.

[image: Interface Builder]

But when I do, the spinning part is placed in the upper corner!  Even stranger, the view the houses it is in the correct place.

[image: iPhone Screen Shot]

I was wondering if anyone can take a guess as to why it isn't in the place it should be.  Also keep in mind that UIImages, and UILabels are in the correct place.  My guess is that the problem is related to animation.  The UIActivityIndicator animates.  I am not sure how that would effect it.

Comment: The animation has anything to do with your problem. It looks like you're using spacing constraints to the edges of the activity indicator's superview; you might try using centerX and centerY constraints instead, since they will keep it centered regardless of the size of the red view.

Comment: Center x and y was the first thing I tried.  If you look at the image you will see that the backgroundColor of the activity Indicator view is red.  If this was a spacing issue then why would the red colored view still be in the right place?